# When are extensional equivalence classes still sets?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $\sim$ denote extensional equivalence.  That is, $y\sim x \Leftrightarrow \forall z(z\in y \leftrightarrow z\in x)$.

Given a set $x$, let $[[x]] := \lbrace y:y\sim x\rbrace$.  Clearly, $\textrm{ZF}$ proves that these classes are sets, for by extensionality they are just singletons.  With a little bit more effort, we can see that $\textrm{ZF}$ without the axiom of extensionality still proves that they are sets:  If $y\sim x$, then $y\subseteq x$ and so $y\in \mathcal{P}(x)$, where $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is any powerset of $x$.  Applying comprehension to $\mathcal{P}(x)$ then gives us some desired set with the same elements as $[[x]]$.

**Question**: Does $\textrm{ZF}$ without the axiom of extensionality and the axiom of powerset still prove that $[[x]]$ is a set?

**Edit:** The intended meaning of "$[[x]]$ is a set" is $\exists y \forall z (z\in y \leftrightarrow z\sim x)$.

Comment: The immediate instinct would be to add a proper class of empty sets, and see what happens.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What do you mean by $\mathcal P(x)$ without extensionality? Are you restating the power set axiom so it reads that for every $x$ there is a unique $y$ such that etc? Are all other axioms restated similarly?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo All other axioms are stated as usual (that is, without any uniqueness requirements). You are correct that I was careless in mentioning $\mathcal{P}(x)$, as there is now no guarantee of its uniqueness.  This doesn't affect the proof, but I will edit to make this clear.

Comment: I still don't understand. How do you apply comprehension without uniqueness? All you get is that there is a set with the same elements as your equivalence class (whatever that is). This is not the same as saying that your equivalence class is a set. If it is, don't we need an additional axiom stating this (that if a class and a set have the same elements, then the class is a set)?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo When I say that some class is a set, my intended meaning is that there is a set with exactly the same elements as this class.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Here's one way to see this. Let $\kappa$ be a regular uncountable cardinal. By recursion we can define a series of structures $\langle A_\alpha, \in_\alpha\rangle$ for $\alpha\leq\kappa$. First, we let $A_0$ and $\in_0$ be empty. Then we make $\langle A_{\alpha+1}, \in_{\alpha+1}\rangle$ relate something new to the elements of every less than $\kappa$ sized subset of $A_\alpha$. For instance, suppose $x\subseteq A_\alpha$ has size less than $\kappa$. Then we pick some $y\not\in \bigcup_{\beta\leq \alpha} A_\beta$ and define $\in_{\alpha+1}$ such that $z\in_{\alpha+1} y$ just in case $z\in x$. At limits we take unions.

It is straightforward to check that $\langle A_\kappa, \in_\kappa\rangle$ satisfies ZF minus Powerset minus Extensionality. But because we add a new empty set at each successor stage, there will be $\kappa$ many empty sets and thus no set containing all of them.